# .contains(" ; ") is not working for check the value in cell in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I using .contains() to check the value in the DataGridView Csv cell whether it's contain the value then i want to remove or replace or not.

Everything works fine but the line .contain(";") is not working.

By going through my code, i hope that u can understand what i'm trying to do.

```
if (!cellV.Contains("="))
     {
           continue;
     }
      //if contain P =, replace P= with "" coz only want the value, don want the P = for calculation
      else if (cellV.Contains("P = "))
     {
             cellV = cellV.Replace("P = ", "");
     }
       else if (cellV.Contains("F = n/a"))
     {
             cellV = cellV.Replace("F = n/a", "0");

     }
       else if (cellV.Contains("F = "))
     {
             cellV = cellV.Replace("F = ", "");
     }
       else if (cellV.Contains(" ; "))
     {
              cellV = cellV.Replace(" ; ", "");
     }
                Console.WriteLine(cellV);
```

Here is the output

```
 19.8494
 0
 18
 0 ; 0 ; 0
 11988
 1
 31
 38
 0
 0
 2.3149
```

Also, i'd tried to leave a blank space neither remove it (";" or " ;" and so on) but it is not working as well.

Or it cannot read the ";" because it is a special character?

I search through the net already but i can't found any of this.

Comment: to the one who down vote , can u please tell me the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `else - if`. That means, if that cell already contained on of the previously checked strings the ";" will not be removed. Try this:

```
 if (!cellV.Contains("="))
 {
       continue;
 }
  //if contain P =, replace P= with "" coz only want the value, don want the P = for calculation
 if (cellV.Contains("P = "))
 {
         cellV = cellV.Replace("P = ", "");
 }
 if (cellV.Contains("F = n/a"))
 {
         cellV = cellV.Replace("F = n/a", "0");

 }
 if (cellV.Contains("F = "))
 {
         cellV = cellV.Replace("F = ", "");
 }
 if (cellV.Contains(" ; "))
 {
          cellV = cellV.Replace(" ; ", "");
 }
            Console.WriteLine(cellV);
```

Or better:

```
if (!cellV.Contains("="))
{
    continue;
}

cellV = cellV.Replace("P = ", "")
             .Replace("F = n/a", "0")
             .Replace("F = ", "")
             .Replace(" ; ", "");

Console.WriteLine(cellV);
```

Answer (score 1):

You start your code block with 
  `if (!cellV.Contains("=")) continue`

All the cases contain a `=` but the case where you check `;` does not contain a `=`.

Remove the first if or check also for the `;` character.

Like this:

```
     if (!cellV.Contains("=") && !cellV.Contains(";"))
     {
           continue;
     }
     ... // Other checks
     Console.WriteLine(cellV);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all you want just `Replace` *chaining*

```
if (cellV.Contains("="))
  cellV = cellV
    .Replace("P = ", "")
    .Replace("F = n/a", "0")
    .Replace("F = ", "")
    .Replace(" ; ", "");
```

**Edit:** what's going on (cause of the misbehaviour). Imagine that you have a string

```
cellCV = "P = 123;";
```

you have to replace **both** `"P = "` fragment **and** `";"`. However, your code as it implemented (`else if`) can perform just **one** branch (that's `else if (cellV.Contains("P = "))`)

Comment: While this solves the problem, OP will never know what caused it ;-)